# Using "redouble" with an object other than "effort"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

While there is nothing in the definition to say otherwise, I can't think of any examples where I've seen the transitive verb "redouble" have an object other than "effort".

Would a phrase like "redouble our optimism" or "redouble our resolve" sound weird?

Comment: There are some broadened usages: 'Wrexham redouble UK Railway Discussion' /  'Tragedy must redouble quest to make air travel ever safer', but there's an obvious implied 'effort/s' here. The odd example can also be found with 'positive qualities // strivings' referents for the direct object. Acceptable, but rarely used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expressions seem fine:

> [Water Supply Risks and Water Management Opportunities](http://repository.uchastings.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1180&context=faculty_scholarship) by BE Gray
>   - ‎2008
>
> We will need to **redouble our optimism, creativity, and commitment**
>   to see through to the light.

Also, one finds at Google Books, as results of this search

["redouble our"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22redouble+our%22)

things like:

redouble our vigilance

redouble our precautions

redouble our fervour

redouble our outrage

redouble our reforming capacity